# What is " (Dialog) Input [ ] := " after evaluating a cell?

Tags: evaluation, cells

I have done a time-consuming run and calculation. After many hours ( about 7 hours!), the black color which shows that the cell is evaluating, turn into gray and a strange text appears like this :

```
(Dialog) Input[157]:= (* my code in the cell *)
```

Does anyone know what it is and why this is happening ?!

Comment: @Kuba : Could you please elaborate it more ?!

Comment: This means that you have interrupted the calculation.  Most likely you did not do this through using the `Dialog` function but by using the Evaluation -> Interrupt Evaluation item or accidentally pressing the corresponding shortcut key.  You can resume by evaluating `Return[]`.

Comment: @ Szabolcs : As you said, I haven't used `Dialog` function and it the notebook was evaluated by `Evaluating` function. You mean that there is no error in my code and it was just a coincidence ?! Because it's a long code with a huge load of lists of number!

Answer (score 2):

As stated in comments:

> This means that you have interrupted the calculation. Most likely you did not do this through using the `Dialog` function but by using the `Evaluation -> Interrupt Evaluation` item or accidentally pressing the corresponding shortcut key. You can resume by evaluating `Return[]`.

Comment: This is a clarification to those who came to Mathematica since version 10: in v10 the Interrupt Evaluation menu item was removed, though the shortcut key (Option-Command-. on Mac) still works.